# Dynamically filter out a JSON response in React

Tags: arrays, reactjs, loops, jsx

I'm trying to filter out a JSON response on the basis of an static array. 
So for example, if the response is something like following

```
{
   "Name":React, 
   "Version": 9.0, 
   "Level": Intermediate, 
   "Machine": Desktop, 
   "Release date": 2019-08-10
}
```

. This is stored in the state of the component.
And the array is, say

```
[ "Version", "Release date"]
```

and this is coming through props.
Now I want to filter the json data using this array. So, that means if we use the given example, I should only be able to display the fields version and release date!
Is there a way to do it?
Then how is it proper to iterate through each of them and exactly where? Like should it be filtered within the componentDidMount function or we need to define another function for it?

I'm a newbie working on React and JSX.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure i understood exactly your objective, but let's try it.

First, you want to set the state with the response.
So you must set a state `response: {}` in the constructor. Have you done that?
If so, great! 
Now, when you get the response, either using axios.get() or fetch(), you set the response to the state.

```
axios
    .get(url)
    .then(res => { this.setState({ response: res }); }) //sets JSON object to state
    .catch(e => console.log(e)); //return a error to the console if it fails
```

(PS: if you use the react fetch() function, you first need to convert the response to JSON using `.json();` before using setState)

But I don't understand your array question.
You want to append to an array the values of ReleaseDate and Version? 
Or simply replace its data?

Perhaps you would want to crate an array of objects, where each object has a version and release date field. Or maybe even append the whole response to this array (sorta like keeping a history of previous responses) and accessing the version and date fields directly.

Could you clarify?

Also, just a tip:
You asked if you should iterate in componentDidMount or another function. I would recommend you creating a function like `readResponse` and call it in componentDidMount(), except when you're **absolutely** sure that it won't need to be called again. Let's say you will make more than 1 request at this page, you'll need to call it more than once.

AFTER QUESTION EDIT:

@VarnikaChaturvedi  Sorry for the late response. I guess i understood your question. 
Here's what we can do: 
Let's use the same code i mentioned before, but on a little different:

```
axios
    .get(url)
    .then(res => { 
        this.setState({ response: res.data });
        myArray.push({ 
            "Version": res.data.get("Version"), 
            "Release date": res.data.get("Release date")
        });
    })
    .catch(e => console.log(e));


    // what is supposed to happen is add a object containing version 
    // and release date to a already defined array named myArray
```

PS: i'm typing this from memory, so there probably is a syntax error or something silly, so read the errors if there is any.

Comment: Hi Just updated the question, can you have a look now?

Comment: @VarnikaChaturvedi Sorry for the late response. I edited my original response to try to solve your problem. Hope it helps.
Also, if your problem is solved, don't forget to mark the question as SOLVED.
Good luck!